# getting broken image icon on React app on every image

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

All the images are displayed as broken image icon on my React app.[Here I'm trying to display this image but this too appears as broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRQiH.png)

Comment: You need to import the image...

Comment: And please post the code in question vs a screenshot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to call images inside your src folder you have to import it first.

```
import neonSpace  from './neon-space.jpg';
```

and alter you can use it in your  like this:

```
<img src={neonSpace} />
```

If you want to call the image only with the URL you must have to put your image in your `public` folder. (sibling folder of `src`)

```
<img src='./neon-space.jpg' />
```

Hope it helps!